# Stopping Windows Service from C# code doesn't work

Tags: c#, service, cmd

My code has to stop a service. I'm using the code below:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
processInfo.FileName = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%") + @"\System32\cmd.exe";
processInfo.Arguments = "sc stop SERVICENAME";
processInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
processInfo.Verb = "runas"; //The process should start with elevated permissions

Process process = new Process() { EnableRaisingEvents = true, StartInfo = processInfo };
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I then check the service state from a `CMD` window (manually, not in my program) with the following command: `sc SERVICENAME query`. But the state is still `RUNNING`.

When I stop it opening `cmd` as Administrator and executing the same commands (`sc stop SERVICENAME`), it just works.

Any thoughts about why it doesn't work from my code?

Comment: Are you running your code as Administrator?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing `cmd.exe` with `sc stop SERVICENAME` as arguments won't do anything.  It will only start the command prompt.

To fix your problem, simply execute `sc.exe` directly, passing `stop SERVICENAME` as the arguments.

```
// ...
processInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "sc.exe");
processInfo.Arguments = "stop SERVICENAME";
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks @sstan! Works just fine. I thought Arguments property would work out with cmd, just like a command line.

Comment: An alternative would be to use the `ControlService` winapi function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682108(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You _can_ run `sc` within a new `cmd` instance, but in that case you need to precede the arguments (the `sc` command line) with `/C`, so you have `processInfo.FileName = [...] + @"\System32\cmd.exe";` and `processInfo.Arguments = "/C sc [...]";`;

Answer (score 3):

With C# and .NET, it is better if you use the [ServiceController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller(v=vs.110).aspx) class like this:

```
ServiceController controller = new ServiceController("SERVICENAME");

controller.Stop();
```